# How to create image from snapshot using aws sdk java

Tags: aws-sdk

We can create image from existing snapshot using AWS management console. However, If I want to do same thing using AWS SDK Java - I could not find any API supporting this. Seems, we can create image only from instance, not from snapshot using SDK Java as shown below:

We can use **withInstanceId(java.lang.String instanceId)** method of **CreateImageRequest** class, but there is no supporting method for snapshot id for image creation.
**Can someone please let me know how to create image from snapshot using SDK Java?**

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`importImage`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2.html#importImage()):

```
ImportImageResult importImage(ImportImageRequest importImageRequest)
                              throws AmazonServiceException,
                                     AmazonClientException
```

> Import single or multi-volume disk images or EBS snapshots into an Amazon Machine Image (AMI).